# Updating User Profile photo O365 using Powershell Script

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, user-profile

I am using PowerShell script for updating the User profile properties of nearly 17 items from a Picture library(named 'Employee Details') in a site. All fields get updated except Profile photo.

When I try to update "PictureURL" property, the previous image in my User Profile gets removed, and my new photo didn't gets updated, even though I waited more than 10 hours.

**Note:** I am updating the user's photo who doesn't have exchange online license. In this case how can I update User photo. Kindly give me the solution to Update user profile photo.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm facing the very same issue and want to update the profile photo of users directly in SharePoint Online user profile using Powershell

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to update the "PictureURL" property with a link to your picture in "Employee Details"? I think that doesn't work because of a wrong location. It might be possible that your "Employee Details" library is not accessible for everyone in your organisation.

This is not a very clean solution, I guess, but one that works:

1. Copy your pictures to the "profile pictures" folder in https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos
2. Set the "PictureURL" property to the picture in https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos via PowerShell

The thumbnails won't get generated this way.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 you want to use the Exchange PowerShell to update the Photo.

`Set-UserPhoto -Identity "Ruby Golden" -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Ruby.jpg"))`